# toggle form field type with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to add a checkbox or radio buttons on a page to toggle form fields between input type "text" and "password"?

The reason I put jQuery in subject line because I'm trying to use it exclusively and I have a lot of confidence in its potential. :)

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:
I need to toggle because I need the user an ability to come back and review previously entered input. (Tip: This is not a login script.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use a little clever jquery to accomplish this illusion.

**LIVE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/aaK9E/2/

Given the following HTML / CSS:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" size="50" id="t" name="passtext" />
<input type="password" size="50" id="p" name="passpass" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="c">Show Password
```

**CSS**

```
#t{display:none;}
```

You can use the checkbox as a toggle like this

```
var showPass=false;
$('#c').change(function(){
    showPass = ($('#c:checked').length>0);
    if (showPass){
        $('#p').hide();
        $('#t').show();
    }else{
        $('#t').hide();
        $('#p').show();
    }
});
```

Now, you'll need to make sure the two text boxes always have the same value. When one changes, you want to change the other one and visa-versa. For that you'll need to use the following JS

```
$('#p').change(function(){
    if (!showPass) //password box is showing. sync its value to the textbox
        $('#t').val($('#p').val());
});
$('#t').change(function(){
    if (showPass) //textbox is showing. sync its value to the password box
        $('#p').val($('#t').val());
});
```

If both `passtext` and `passpass` are in the same form, they will both be passed to the receiver, and they will both have the same value since we are synching them using (for example with PHP) `$variableName = $_REQUEST['passpass'];`

Comment: +1 for jsfiddle example. It may not work for me as I have quite a few fieds on the page that change dynamically. But thanks for this code, I may use this too sometime.

Comment: This can be easily adapted to accommodate any number of elements.

Comment: I think the code would be shorter if the id and name attributes were exchanged as well, no need for the onChange hook.

Comment: Why wouldn't you need the onchange hook? You still need to sync the values of the two objects - unless I'm missing something...

Answer (score 8):

I ended up simplifying this into the following solution:

```
$('input#checkbox').change(function(){
    var type    = ($(this).is(':checked') ? 'text' : 'password'), 
        input   = $('input#password'),
        replace = input.clone().attr('type', type)
        input.replaceWith(replace);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
instead of cloning input type, you can use the simple logic of toggling.
handle--> the button which will cause event.
target--> target input on which you want the toggle to happen.
event type--> event name on which given button will cause toggle on target.
typeChange--> name of type which you want to alter example "text" if you want password type to text type.

    function type_toggle(handle, target, eventType, typeChange) {
    var targetType = $(target).prop("type");
    $(handle).on(eventType, function () {
        if ($(target).prop("type") !== typeChange) {
            $(target).prop("type", typeChange);
        } else {
            $(target).prop("type", targetType);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this solution instead?
http://css-tricks.com/better-password-inputs-iphone-style/

Comment: this is a great plug-in! Thanks for the tip. I can't use it here but I'll use it somewhere else for sure. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can simply toggle the input password fields type property to password/text to achieve the behaviour.

Html Example -

```
<!-- Password field -->
Password: <input type="password" value="FakePSW" id="myInput">

<!-- An element to toggle between password visibility -->
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">Show Password
```

Javascript -

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
    if (x.type === "password") {
       x.type = "text";
    } else {
       x.type = "password";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a field type from password to text and vise versa.  You can create a password and text fields on top of each other and change the visibility/z-index of the field with a radio button

Comment: What about the name though? They will be submitted both? Why can't it be done? I'm almost sure I saw it implemented somewhere. If indeed it is the case, then I can probably use .load() to get appropriate type fields from an external file, right? Sounds convoluted

Comment: this is the only solution that I know of (and am using myself)... you do not have to have the TEXT field on page, you can use jQuery to add it in the position of the password field and then remove the password field... when checkbox is unticked, do the process in reverse... works like a charm ;-)

Comment: Security is the reason.  As you know most browsers star out passwords.  If setup a script that reverted this effect on users you'd be more likely to stand over their shoulder and read users passwords

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14816034/toggle-multiple-password-inputs-with-single-checkbox/15167366#15167366).

The solution is a jQuery plugin (that I wrote) that supports multiple password fields. The source is posted on [github](https://github.com/cbaigorri/password-toggle).

Sample usage:

```
<input type="password" id="inputGroup1">
<input type="password" id="inputGroup2">
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="input-mask" data-toggle='["inputGroup1", "inputGroup2"]'>Toggle Password
</label>
<script>
$('.input-mask').passwordToggle();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// find elements
jQuery("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
 var pwdType = jQuery("#pwd").attr("type");
 var newType = (pwdType === "password")?"text":"password";
 jQuery("#pwd").attr("type", newType);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <div class="row">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/action_page.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10 ">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" value="nikhil_gyan@yahoo.co.in">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" value="password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Show Password</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>  
</div>
```